# Subgroup Count in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query that looks like the following:

```
select
    c.[Name], 
    c.Description, 
    c.ID,
    cd.StartDateTime
from
    Classroom.dbo.Class as c
left join
    Classroom.dbo.Course as co
on
    co.ID = c.CourseID
left join
    Classroom.dbo.Classdate as cd
on
    cd.ClassID = c.ID
where
    co.PublicIndicator = 1
```

This query simply gives me a list of classes along with the dates they're occurring. The relationship is:

- a course can have many classes
- a class can have one course and many class dates
- a class date can only have one class

What I'd like to add is, for the classes with multiple class dates, add a "counter" that can tell me which "instance" of the class I'm dealing with. So something like:

```
Test    test    1   2009-08-19 05:00:00     1
Test    test    1   2009-08-20 05:00:00     2
Test    a       2   2009-10-22 08:00:00     1
Test    a       3   2009-10-30 07:00:00     1
Test    a       5   2009-10-21 11:00:00     1
```

Where the last column is the extra column I'd like to see, indicating that in this scenario, the 2nd row is the second day for this class.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OVER clause should give you what you want.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

```
SELECT c.[Name], c.Description, c.ID, cd.StartDateTime, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.Id Order BY cd.StartDateTime)
  FROM Classroom.dbo.Class as c
  LEFT JOIN Classroom.dbo.Course as co
    ON co.ID = c.CourseID
  LEFT JOIN Classroom.dbo.Classdate as cd
    ON cd.ClassID = c.ID
 WHERE co.PublicIndicator = 1
```

Comment: You need to ORDER BY `cd.startdatetime`, not `c.id` because `c.id` would be the same.  And you can only use OVER with ranking functions, like ROW_NUMBER()...

Comment: That "partition by" is beautiful, didn't know that existed. Thanks!